# Regex to validate price (type of decimal)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, decimal

I have looked through stack**overflow** trying to find a solution to this but with no luck so hence why I have resulted in asking the question..

I have a field on my form which is price, type of decimal this is optional depending on what they have selected from a dropdown, So I cant use the [Required] attribute.

When the form is submitted if they have chosen a value from the dropdown which requires the user to enter a postage price I then need to check this field to make sure its a valid decimal so to do this I have the following

```
public static bool IsValid(decimal postagePrice)
{
   var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$");
   return regex.IsMatch(postagePrice);
}
```

But it complains and says "Argument type decimal is not assignable to parameter type string" which I understand, I also can't use Decimal.TryParse as that expects a string.

How can I resolve this **(I'm not in a position to change the type from decimal to string either)**

Comment: `regex.IsMatch(postagePrice.ToString());` ? Also your regex have a bug; you need to escape the `.` character like `\.`. Also you don't need a regex at all IMHO.

Comment: What is a "valid" decimal in your case? Your method already expects a `decimal postagePrice`, so by definition it is already "valid" in the *usual* case.

Comment: If you already have a decimal, why do you need to validate is as if it was a string?

Comment: If its optional, look at using one of the [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `RequiredIf` attributes

Comment: This foolproof required if looks quite good but can the user can select 2 potential options from the drop-down and both values will require the posrage to be filled in, also when it comes to validating the decimal it needs to allow for 0.1 Up to  xx,xxx.xx format

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to verify that the value has at most two decimal positions, you could use a modulo:

```
public static bool IsValid(decimal postagePrice)
{
    return postagePrice % 0.01m == 0m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) work on strings - it's that simple.

So in one way or another you'll need to covert the decimal to a string before using a regex to validate it.